# jquery how can I use apostrophe is statment

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery('#Level_of_Interest__c option[value="Bachelor's"]').attr("selected","selected")
```

this is the code I am trying to run but because of the " ' " on Bachelor's I am getting a error, any one has any ideas?

Comment: Put a backslash before it to escape it. `\'`

Comment: Use \ to escape it

Answer (score 0):

You can use backslash:

```
//since \ itself is a escape character you need to use \\
jQuery('#Level_of_Interest__c option[value="Bachelor\\'s"]')
   .attr("selected","selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

single backslash is enough.

```
$('#Level_of_Interest__c option[value="Bachelor\'s"]').attr("selected","selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to escape it using backslash

```
jQuery('#Level_of_Interest__c option[value="Bachelor\'s"]').attr("selected","selected");
```